# Конвертация String^ с юникод символами в char*

Tags: c#, строки, c++-cli

И снова проблема со строками (юникод).

Как известно в [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) объект `System.String` содержит *unicode* строку. При передаче параметров строк в [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), мне необходимо перекодировать данную строку в мульти-байтовую кодировку, без потери данных. Я просто не понимаю как сделать это правильно дабы открыть в `libvlc` файл который содержит *unicode* символы как в пути, так и в названии файла?

При вызове `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(file_location);` все символы не поддерживающиеся `char*` передаются как вопросы.
При этом libvlc отдает ошибку как `unknown error`, а в консоли видно что он пытается открыть файл как `c:/path/to/???.mp3`

```
void vlc_media::open_file(String ^ file_location) {
    release_media();

    const char* vlc_error;

    IntPtr tmpPtr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(file_location);

    char* file_loc = reinterpret_cast<char*>(tmpPtr.ToPointer());

    libvlc_media_t* tmpmptr = libvlc_media_new_path(&m_instance_, file_loc);

    if(!tmpmptr)
    {
        vlc_error = libvlc_errmsg();
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(tmpPtr);
        throw gcnew Exception(gcnew String(vlc_error));
    }


    m_media_ = IntPtr(tmpmptr);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(tmpPtr);
}
```

Comment: ммм, ну правильно, что все символы не поддерживающиеся char* передаются как вопросы. А как вы хотите еще, чтобы они отображались? char - это ASCII. Если они не поддерживаются ASCII, они и не будут отображаться. ASCII кириллицу не поддерживает

Comment: В C++, в отличие от .NET, строки имеют _кодировку_. Какая кодировка строки вам нужна?

Comment: @VladD: Точно не могу сказать но по умолчанию `libvlc` использует кодировку системы. в моем случае `CP1251`

Comment: WideCharToMultiByte?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Он вернет все тоже самое что и `Marshal`

Comment: Но у него есть возможность выбора кодировки. А Marshal всегда лепит  какую-то свою.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Хм, слушайте, а ведь помогло! Теперь все строки содержащие unicode символы после конвертации, открываются `libvlc`, так, как будто там и нет unicode символов! `libvlc` написан на [tag:c] и не поддерживает `wchar_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я надеюсь, что VLC умеет принимать широкие строки. (Это скорее всего так, 
поскольку файловая система у Windows юникодная.) Вам понядобятся заголовки для маршаллирования.

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
using namespace System;
```

В этом случае ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
String^ managed = L"привет мир";
std::wstring utf16 = marshal_as<std::wstring>(managed);
```

Если вам нужно utf-8, то тоже несложно:

```
String^ managed = L"привет мир";
array<Byte>^ managedBytesUtf8 = Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(managed);
pin_ptr<Byte> nativeBytesUtf8 = &managedBytesUtf8[0];
std::string utf8((char*)nativeBytesUtf8, managedBytesUtf8->Length);
```

Comment: А я могу просто скопировать байты из `nativeBytesUtf8` сразу в указатель дабы не содержать промежуточный объект? `m_value = reinterpret_cast<char*>(calloc(managedBytesUtf8->Length + 1, sizeof(char))); strcpy_s(m_value, managedBytesUtf8->Length +1, reinterpret_cast<char*>(nativeBytesUtf8));`

Comment: @Yami: По идее можно, но я бы использовал `static_cast` вместо `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Прибегнул к такому решению, работает на ура:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace System;

namespace yami {
    namespace vlc {
        ref class vlc_string {
        private:
            char* m_value;
            HRESULT __fastcall UnicodeToAnsi(LPCOLESTR pszW, LPSTR* ppszA);
        public:
            vlc_string(String^ string);
            ~vlc_string();
            static char* operator &(vlc_string^ vlc_str);
        };
    }
}
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vlc_string.h"

namespace yami {
    namespace vlc {

        HRESULT vlc_string::UnicodeToAnsi(LPCOLESTR pszW, LPSTR * ppszA) {
            ULONG cbAnsi, cCharacters;
            DWORD dwError;

            if (pszW == NULL)
            {
                *ppszA = NULL;
                return NOERROR;
            }

            cCharacters = wcslen(pszW) + 1;
            cbAnsi = cCharacters * 2;
            *ppszA = reinterpret_cast<char*>(malloc(cbAnsi));
            if (NULL == *ppszA)
                return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            if (0 == WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszW, cCharacters, *ppszA,
                cbAnsi, NULL, NULL))
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
                free(*ppszA);
                *ppszA = NULL;
                return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
            }
            return NOERROR;
        }

        vlc_string::vlc_string(String^ string) : m_value(nullptr) {
            IntPtr tmpPtr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(string);
            wchar_t* buffer = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(tmpPtr.ToPointer());
            char* tmp;
            HRESULT result = UnicodeToAnsi(buffer, &tmp);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                throw gcnew System::Runtime::InteropServices::COMException("Failed to convert String to vlc_string");
            }
            m_value = new char[strlen(tmp)];
            strcpy(m_value, tmp);
            free(tmp); // чуть не забыл освободить.
            System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeHGlobal(tmpPtr);
        }

        char* vlc_string::operator&(vlc_string ^ value) {
            // используем reinterpret_cast т.к. в классе лежит interop_ptr, а не нативный указатель
            return reinterpret_cast<char*>(value->m_value);
        }

        vlc_string::~vlc_string() {
            if(m_value)
                free(m_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
void vlc_media::open_file(String ^ file_location) {
    release_media();

    const char* vlc_error;

    vlc_string^ path = gcnew vlc_string(file_location);

    libvlc_media_t* tmpmptr = libvlc_media_new_path(&m_instance_, &path);

    if (!tmpmptr)
    {
        vlc_error = libvlc_errmsg();
        delete path;
        throw gcnew Exception(gcnew String(vlc_error));
    }

    m_media_ = IntPtr(tmpmptr);
    delete path;
}
```

Comment: Как ужасно длинно. Почему не marshal_as?

Comment: @VladD: С marshal_as еще не приходилось работать

Comment: @VladD: Если можно пример, и хотел бы узнать используя marshal_as, нужно ли освобождать объект?

Comment: Marshal_as вроде не умеет в UTF8. Из средств NET тут скорее Encoding нужен